# Playing a wav file to b-leg in freeswitch using lua

Tags: lua, freeswitch

How can I play a wave file to b-leg in freeswitch before connecting with the caller?
How can this be done in the dialplan or do I need to script in lua?

Scenario is I have a few phone numbers but only one phone. It would be helpful to play a wave file so I can determine which number was dialed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the dialplan.xml you don't need Lua.
In dialplan.xml under the context place something like this:

```html
<extension name="call">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression=".*">    
           <action application="answer"/>
         <action application="playback" data="/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/yourSoundHere.wav"/>
          <action application="bridge" data="user/${destination_number}"/>
          <action application="answer"/>
        </condition>
</extension>
```

Note that the expression uses Regex, so .* will match any number that is being called, therefore for every call it'll play the sound that wav before ringing the user.

Comment: @Razormind, if this answers your question, then click the little check-mark, to the left to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task with Perl, and it didn't appear to be so easy. I had to launch a second Perl script which originated the call to the user, played the sound, asked for DTMF confirmation, and then connected the inbound call. Also I made a prototype in Go, using the ESL connection, and it appeared much easier because Go has native multithreading.

This is the Perl code, with explanations in Jira FS-6746: https://github.com/xlab1/freeswitch_secretary_bug

This is a working prototype in Go: https://github.com/xlab1/go-fs-secretary-prototype